# Standalone components in Angular doesn't load in router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-standalone-components

Alright, today I tried to implement standalone components in my app. Just to investigate how it works. So on initial launch it's loading correctly. But, here is the thing.

[image]
Here I have a regular component with navigation and `router-outlet`. and here are the routes for this feature. The injected service is just a config from localStorage, that has boolean flags that enable or disable features.

[image]

So, currently it looks like this.

[image]
All good.

**If I try to move to Time Limits tab, the route changes, but the component stays the same. And it will only work, when I try to move to not lazy loaded component, like Self Exclusion. Also it will work if I remove the `loadComonent` function and set `component` prop instead. Any ideas, why this is happening ?**